# Issue: in Hybris backofice wizard is not opening on clicking on icon

Tags: widget, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I like to have wizard-like we have on Solar hot indexing, and on my custom button wizard is not opening,my custom button is comming on items list view beside delete button
For this, I try the following code
can you please help what I am trying wrong here

1. Created definition.xml in action folder and create action class, configure the same in config.xml
2. Created definition.xml in widget folder, controller class and widget connections in widget.xml

What should be widgetdefinationid?
Getting a warring on console WARN  [hybrisHTTP30] [DefaultActionRenderer] Illegal configuration! Action class 'de.hybris.platform.actions.MyAction' requires 'de.hybris...path.myModel' as input, yet configured to be used in context of 'java.lang.String'

definition.xml

```xml
<action-definition id="path.actions.MyAction" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/action-definition.xsd">
    <name>MyAction</name>
    <description>MyAction</description>
    <author>Me</author>
    <version>0.1</version>  

    <actionClassName>path.actions.MyAction</actionClassName>

    <inputType>de.hybris.platform.services.model.myModel</inputType>
    <outputType>java.lang.Object</outputType>
    <iconUri>icons/icon_action_search_prices_default.png</iconUri>

    <sockets>
        <output id="typeCode" type="java.lang.String" /> 
    </sockets> 
</action-definition>
```

MyAction class

```cs
public class MyAction extends AbstractComponentWidgetAdapterAware
        implements CockpitAction<myModel, myModel>
{
    private static final String SOCKET_OUT_CURRENT_PRINCIPAL = "typeCode";

    @Override
    public ActionResult<myModel> perform(final ActionContext<myModel> ctx)
    {

        ActionResult<myModel> result = new ActionResult<>(ActionResult.ERROR);
        if (ctx.getData() != null)
        {

            sendOutput(SOCKET_OUT_CURRENT_PRINCIPAL, ctx.getCode());
            result = new ActionResult<>(ActionResult.SUCCESS);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

config.xml

```xml
<context type="testtype" component="listviewactions" merge-by="type">
    <y:actions xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
        <y:group qualifier="common">
            <y:action action-id="path.actions.MyAction" property="pageable.typeCode"/>
        </y:group>
    </y:actions>
</context>
```

defination.xml in widget folder

```xml
<widget-definition id="abc.searchWidget" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/widget-definition.xsd">
    <name>Search POC</name>
    <description>A widget to</description>
    <defaultTitle></defaultTitle>
    <author>me</author>
    <version>0.1</version>
        <view src="searchPoc.zul"/>
    <keywords>
        <keyword>SearchPocWidget</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <controller class="de.hybris.platform.controller.MySearchController"/>
    <sockets>
        <input id="inputObjectInput" type="java.lang.Object" />
        <output id="refreshUI" type="java.lang.Object" />
    </sockets>
</widget-definition>
```

widgets.xml

```xml
<widget-extension widgetId="hmc2list" >

   <widget id="my-search-widget" widgetDefinitionId="com.hybris.cockpitng.backoffice.referenceadvancedsearchgroup"
    slotId="cockpitWidgetChildrenInvisible" template="true" title="my serach button">
        <widget id="mysearchwidget"
            widgetDefinitionId="abc.searchWidget"
            slotId="children" template="false" title=" widget"
            >
        </widget>
       </widget>
      <setting key="_width" type="String">70%</setting>
        <setting key="_height" type="String">75%</setting>

</widget-extension>
<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="path.actions.MyAction" outputId="typeCode" targetWidgetId="my-search-widget" inputId="activate" />
```

zul file

```html
<widget xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <style src="${wr}/default.css"/>
    <div>
        <hlayout>
        hi
        </hlayout>
    </div>
</widget>
```

```cs
public class MySearchController extends DefaultWidgetController
{
    private Textbox searchInput;


    @ViewEvent(componentID = "searchBtn", eventName = Events.ON_CLICK)
    public void doSearch() throws InterruptedException
    {
        final List<String> result = search(searchInput.getText());
        Messagebox.show(result.get(0));
    }

    public List<String> search(final String text)
    {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add(text);
        result.add("Hello");
        result.add("Cockpit NG");


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: [K B Manjunath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14477421) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64425128/12695027) saying "did you tried instance-settings for your custom widget in custom-backoffice-widget.xml file?"